# regular expression phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Can somebody give me the regex for phone number. It can be entered in the format of XXX-XXX-XXXX or (XXX)-XXX-XXXX or XX-XXX-XXXX or XXXXXXXXX

Heres what I have:

```
/\d{2,3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Answer (score 1):

Brute force/easily maintained/easily read/I think is what you have.

`(\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d)|(\(\d\d\d\)\-\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d)|(\d\d\-\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d)|(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)`

Or if you prefer:

`(\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4})|(\(\d{3})\-\d{3}\-\d{4})|(\d{2}-\d{3}\-\d{4})|(\d{9})`

Answer (score 0):

```
((\d{2,3}|\(\d{3}\))-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{9})
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly you care about the digits:

```
    /^([()-]*\d)[()-]*){9,10}$/.test(string);

    or even

    /^(\D*\d\D*){9,10}/.test(string);
```